# Writing MAT files: Access violation writing location after 508 successful calls

Tags: c++, mat-file

I'm running a 64-bit C++ program in VS2012 that processes images and writes the results to a MAT file. For whatever reason, after 508 working iterations, I get:

"Unhandled exception at ____ (libmat.dll) in Program.exe:____. Access violation writing location ____." (Underscores represent address locations)

However, if I restart the program on image number 509 (changing nothing else; just a restart), it works just fine for the next 508 images and then hands me the same error again.

A comment on an earlier, less-detailed post said it may be some memory issue. Perhaps I'm not handling garbage collection properly? I can't figure it out though.

For the record, all of the data being saved to files ends up in a 127x47 (row x col) double matrix. That means each of the 508 successful files contained 5969 doubles (plus whatever metadata goes into a MAT file). Perhaps some memory limit gets reached because I don't clear it properly?

The code in question is below:

```
void writeMat (void * data, int rows, int cols, std::string fname)
{
    // Copies data to MATLAB format matrix
    mxArray * mat;
    mat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(rows, cols, mxREAL);
    memcpy((void*)mxGetPr(mat), data, rows * cols * sizeof(double));

    // Creates output file
    MATFile * output;
    std::string matFilename = fname + ".mat"; //  Output filename
    std::string varName = "tmp"; // Storage variable in MAT file
    output = matOpen(matFilename.c_str(), "w"); // Opens MAT file for writing
    if (output == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating file");
    }

    // Adds data variable to MAT file
    int status = matPutVariable(output, varName.c_str(), mat);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        printf("Error writing mat file");
    }

    mxDestroyArray(mat); // Free up memory
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that you're running out of file handles, because you don't appear to call `matClose` - however you have error checking on `matOpen` so this doesn't completely explain what you're seeing.

Comment: We can only guess if that was the only problem. Use your debugger and Valgrind.

Comment: @marcman: usually there is an upper limit on number of open files - I'm guessing it's 512 on your system, so given that there are already a few open files then that might explain the failure on the 508th iteration. Still, the call to `matOpen` should just fail gracefully - you shouldn't get a crash, but who knows...

Comment: @marcman: great - I've combined the comments into an answer below now, for any future visitors with a similar problem - feel free to up-vote/accept it if you care to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are running out of file handles, because you keep calling `matOpen` but then don't subsequently call `matClose`. Most systems impose an upper limit on the number of concurrently open files - it would appear that on your system this limit is 512 - there are already a few files open, so when you get to around the 508th iteration you run out of file handles.

Having said that, you should not see a crash - you have error checking on matOpen and this should fail gracefully when you try to open too many files, but evidently it doesn't!